# What filesystems can an Airport Extreme read?/write?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, external-hard-drive, filesystems, nas, airport-extreme

As a follow-up to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/97150/can-airport-extremes-handle-ntfs-external-drives) question, which fileystems can the Apple Airport Extreme interface wih via the usb port?

NTFS seems to be out, and FAT32 and HFS+ both seem to be in.  Can anyone  confirm that? Is there an official list of what it can and can't handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT16, FAT32 and HFS+ volumes can be mounted.

*[Source: AirPort: How to mount an AirPort Extreme USB hard disk volume in Mac OS X and Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1331)*

p.s.: if you want to format large volumes with FAT32, the [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://download.chip.eu/en/USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool_176935.html) will come in handy.